# meaningfulness of using typescript after 2.1 relase

Tags: typescript, types

can anyone tell me what is the purpose of using typescript today? I was certain that people use typescript mainly to avoid some bugs caused by types. But after v 2.1 the code like below is acceptable:

```
let i;

let aNumber = (x:number) => {
  x = 52;
  console.log(x);
}

aNumber(i);

let aString = (x:string) => {
  x = 'strung';
  console.log(x);
}

aString(i);
```

that really staggers my imagination... Am I close-minded or typescript authors are? Thanks for fair answers!

Regards,
crova

Answer (score 1):

You can actually configure the handling of (`null` and) `undefined` types. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#null-and-undefined:

> By default `null` and `undefined` are subtypes of all other types. That means you can assign `null` and `undefined` to something like `number`.
>
> However, when using the `--strictNullChecks` flag, `null` and `undefined` are only assignable to `void` and their respective types. This helps avoid many common errors. In cases where you want to pass in either a `string` or `null` or `undefined`, you can use the union type `string | null | undefined`.

Also see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

The `strictNullChecks` compiler flag has actually been [introduced in TypeScript 2.0](https://ariya.io/2016/10/typescript-2-and-strict-null-checking).

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the `strictNullChecks` compiler option, your code throws errors saying "undefined is not assignable to number".

Take a look at the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Before v2.1 unintialized variables were implicitly inferred as `any` which was changed after v2.1's [improved type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#improved-any-inference).